# How do you show inline line numbers on git patches?

Tags: git

I would like to be able to display the line numbers of `git log -p` inline, like it is with `git blame`, instead of the range being given before. Is this possible?

Comment: Which line numbers?  When you look at a patch, the line numbers are different before and after the patch.

Comment: @DietrichEpp that's true. When it generates the patch it shows the `-`  subtraction lines and the `+` addition lines. They both can have corresponding line numbers from before and after the patch. The numbers of lines outside of the `-` and `+` lines provided for context  wouldn't have consistent line numbers though.